# Illustrator: Opacity Mask is not moving/resizing along with object it masks, if the masked object is a Mesh object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, mask, gradient-mesh

I need to move/resize the artwork which includes an opacity masked object, in which both the mask and the object being masked are different Gradient Mesh objects.

In the Transparency panel, no matter if the mask and the object have the link icon between them turned on or off, moving them simultaneously simply does not work, it only moves one of the two, not both. Of course I make sure to Select All prior to moving.

In my Preferences I tried both checking and unchecking 'Object Selection by Path Only'.
The only way to circumvent this is to turn every such opacity masked mesh object into a Symbol. Not very elegant solution though.

Edit:
Confirming it is a **local issue** on CS6 and it occurs exclusively if the **object that is being masked** is a mesh object. The issue can be circumvented by simply turning the mesh object into a group prior to masking it. Edited the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Transparency panel... you *have* clicked the art thumbnail so it's active, right?

You can tell the **active** thumbnail by the colored border around it in the Transparency Panel.

If the *mask* thumbnail is the active thumbnail (meaning you are working on the mask) then ONLY the mask will move, regardless of the chain icon.

Basically, if the **mask is active** only the *mask* will be altered, and that includes moving it.

This has nothing to do with meshes specifically.

Here's a heavily dithered animation of a mesh masking a mesh using Illustrator CS6:

[image]

---

Note this is how AI has *always* treated Opacity masks.. but I can't test in CC2020 at this time. It *could* be possible there's some bug in CC2020 which is unknown to me.

Comment: Yes, in Transparency panel, it is impossible to have both the thumbnail of the Mask and thumbnail of the object clicked as active (coloured border around thumbnail). So can it be confirmed that it is not possible to move both? Please see screencast for better understanding of the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SUYA6-npJfQTQYNscp-RZW7gsJBlCjUC/view

Comment: @GordanKarabogdan Correct you can not highlight both thumbnails simultaneously. That's standard. Please re-read what I've written above. In order to move the artwork **and** mask together, you **must** have the artwork thumbnail highlighted in the Transparency Panel. Your video would allude to a **problem** or perhaps bug. The thumbnails show things moving, but clearly on the artboard the art isn't moving.

Comment: i.e. I agree.. your video shows you have some odd, non-standard, issue. Perhaps try it on a new document to see if it works correctly. What version of AI are you using?

Comment: It is CS6. Thumbnails in Transparency Panel showing movement is more like actually showing zooming in/out according to the bounding box of both objects and relative to the highlighted one. With more distance between the two, the frame zooms out to show them both. It seems like it shows movement of both, but it is not. Tried in new document, same occurrence.

Comment: @GordanKarabogdan Okay well I can test CS6 here (I actually prefer CS6) and I don't get that behavior at all. I would start with some genreal troubleshooting.. reset prefs, relaunch app, etc. See the gif animation I've added to the answer. That's what I see in CS6. Note how **your** thumbnails move at all times as if the mask is *always* highlighted. I'm not seeing that when the art thumbnail is highlighted in CS6 here.

Comment: Unfortunately, since this appears to be a **localized** problem for you. We can't effectively troubleshoot the issue here.

Comment: Thank you for confirming it is possible in CS6. Must be something locally then yes. From my side, I found interesting occurrence that the problem arises only when the Object which is being masked is a mesh object. If I use mesh object as a Mask, then the behaviour is normal as expected. Please see my elimination process: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V4DjYw51lPTWVlzgvOz1sBUccED4dn6_/view

Comment: @GordanKarabogdan Again, must be a local issue. In my animation above **both** the object and mask are meshes - no problems.